# Why are the files received from Team Foundation Server giving a corruption error on only one machine?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

We have a dozen developers working in VS2013 with Team Foundation Server 2010.  Only one of these machines is having this problem.  When trying to get latest, an error message is displayed:

"the downloaded file is corrupt. please get the file again"

We've already:
 - cleared the cache on the tfs cache folder on the local machine
 - cleared the cache on the tfs server
 - tried rebooting the local machine

As mentioned before, no one else has this problem.  We're all working on the same project just fine.  Besides sacrificing a goat, we're just not sure what to do.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Any local proxies installed like Charles or Fiddler?  What about anti-virus software that scans web sites and probably installs a web proxy?  Can you install Fiddler and see what is being returned to determine if it's an error page instead of the legitimate content?

Comment: We're not using proxies; however, we did find the solution, which I will post forthwith.. posthaste.. right now!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot replicate the problem but I have found a solution.  I am not sure why or how, but for some reason there was a conflict between VS2013 and VS2010.  The project in question was originally created in VS2013, but the original workspace was created in VS2010 (I know it sounds confusing).  After uninstalling and reinstalling vs2013 and still having no hope, I read some articles about difficulty of updating TFS projects from one version of VS to another.  So I decided I would just try to delete my workspace and get latest from VS2010.  After it finished getting latest, none of the files were corrupt and I was able to work just fine in VS2013.  I have since not been able to recreate the problem.

Solution

VS2013

Step 1: Delete Workspace (In source control explorer select the dropdown next to the label “Workspaces:” and choose the last option of “Workspaces…”

Step 2: Click the Remove Button (This will completely disassociate your project from TFS and all mappings.)

VS2010

Step 3: Get Latest on the project in a new folder.  Then close VS2010.

VS2013

Step 4: Open the project from TFS and PROFIT!

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this exact same issue on my 4th test migration/upgrade from TFS2010 on one server to TFS2013 on another server. It hadn't happened before, and was super annoying to just show up out of the blue after it hadn't been a problem before. I'm new to this company and didn't have VS2010 available, so the suggested solution wasn't an option for me. After a while I found a super simple solution:

Stop the project collection in TFS Administration Console, clear the cache in "Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services_tfs_data\". Restart the project collection. Then, in the Source Control Explorer -> Get Latest.

Comment: Same issue "The downloaded file is corrupt.  Please get the file again." when moving a TFS instance to a new site (not an upgrade, just a move), fixed by clearing the cache.

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar issue caused by the FIPS Algorithm compliance policy being enabled on some of the developers’ workstations and disabled on others.  To resolve this specific issue the FIPS compliance policy must be set identical on all developers’ workstations.  Next get the files with the mismatched hashes from TFS and check them back in again to correct (synchronize) the hash values.

[MSDN forum: TFS 2010 VS2012 Get latetest version: File is corrupt, Works Ok in vs2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a444598-723e-4990-99c2-13209937613d/tfs-2010-vs2012-get-latetest-version-file-is-corrupt-works-ok-in-vs2010?forum=tfsversioncontrol)